# How do I get strftime working? Nothing has been working so far

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to add a timestamp for ffmpeg for capture card recoridngs but its not working at all.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i video="Game Capture HD60 S (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 S (Audio) (#01)" -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 0 -r 29.97 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -threads 12 -flags +ilme+ildct -top 1 -strftime 1 "file-%Y%m%d-%%04d.ts"
```

The output file is basically just "file-%Y%m%d-%%04d.ts", no dates or times. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strftime is not a generic option for all muxers; it is specific to a few.

However, you can work around this by using the segment muxer. The segment muxer is meant for when the output needs to be split across, umm.. segments. However, by setting a very large segment time, it effectively will write a single file.

So,

`ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 100M -i video="Game Capture HD60 S (Video) (#01)":audio="Game Capture HD60 S (Audio) (#01)" -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 0 -r 30000/1001 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -threads 12 -flags +ilme+ildct -top 1 -f segment -segment_time 99999 -strftime 1 "file-%Y%m%d-%%04d.ts"`

(Set r value to exact representation)

Comment: that fixed it! thanks! I do want to get it working in a cmd file cause I don't wanna type the whole command everytime. how do i do that?

Comment: The same string but I think you need to add a % before each existing %.